# legacy-50096): Stopped processing.---seeing this error in TCL scripting

Tags: tcl

seeing this error message in TCL

```
XE> if {$host == "san-palladium-z1-01" || $host == "san-palladium-z1-02"} {db_download } else { exit }
invalid command name "1"
    while executing
"1"
    invoked from within
"if $::error == 1"
    (procedure "error_check" line 2)
    invoked from within
"error_check"
    (procedure "db_download" line 2)
    invoked from within
"db_download "
    (file "xe_run.tcl" line 386)
ERROR (legacy-50096): Stopped processing.
XE>
```

info on error details
why am i seeing his legacy error

Comment: It's something in that `db_download` command. You'd have to include its source and other relevant bits.

Comment: It looks like an unbraced expression for an `if` condition. They were moderately common practice in 7.* because they were a bit faster in some cases (as the Tcl language core was faster at substitutions than the expression engine), but it was always a poor plan. The practice was totally deprecated once 8.0 came out... around 25 years ago.